# How to initialize array length and values simultaneously in new Array()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let’s consider, I have to initialize an Array with some values
So I can achieve this by writing following code.

```js
var arr = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
console.log(arr)
```

Similarly, I have to determine the length of the array before using it. 
So I can achieve this by following code.

```js
var arr = new Array(5)
console.log(arr.length)
```

Finally, I have a following questions ?

- Is it possible to initialize an array with array length and different values (not similar values) simultaneously using new Array() ?
- How to initialize a single integer value using new Array() ?

EDIT:
here, different values refers there are some specific string values.

**I know it is straightforward when using array literals. but that's not exactly what I want.**

Comment: Where are you getting the data you will be populating the array with from?

Comment: Can you provide some examples and touch on why an array literal doesn't work for your use case?

Comment: @ic3b3rg I am not saying array literals won't work in this case.

Comment: `Array.from(new Array(5), (f, ix) => String.fromCharCode(97 + ix))`

Comment: @GMaiolo you can consider any values but not same value

Comment: @Keith let's say I want to add "a", "b", "c", "d" this.

Comment: The array length is given by the number of values you add. Why would you want to specify the number of values *and* the values at the same time? How does this make any sense?

Comment: @varatharajan let s say that you try the code Keith gave to you, it already does exactly what you are asking

Comment: Don't understand the first question. `new Array("a", "b", "c", "d")` in your first sample does already initialize an array of 4 (length of the array) different values. What else do you need exactly?

Comment: @str there are some cases, where I want to initialize the array length to 10. but I want to initialize lesser values only

Comment: `for (let i = 97;i < 122;i++){
 document.writeln("&#00"+i+";")
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

```js
console.log(new Array(5).fill(2));
// [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

> Is it possible to initialize an array with array length and values simultaneously using `new Array()` ?

As far as I know, this isn't possible yet.

> How to initialize a single integer value using new Array() ?

That would be `k => new Array(1).fill(k)`. But if I had to choose, I'd use `k => [k]`. Note it is recommended not to use `new Array()` in other scenarios than to initialize it's lenght. But even then, you should rather be sure you are giving it an integer because the behaviour of `new Array(n)` is a bit erratic, and won't throw you an error when you wish it did.

Actually, I wish it was not possible to initialize an array with value using `new Array()`. The worst being using `new Array(...args)`, whose behaviour will change dramatically when `args` is `[5]`. You should stick to `[]` arrays if you want to initialize an array with values.

- `Array("")` gives `[""]`
- Similarly `Array([])` gives `[[]]` and `Array({})`, `[{}]`
- `Array(5)` gives an array with 5 empty slots
- `Array(2.5)` produces an `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length`.
- Also, `Array()` gives `[]`

Note: This is Chromium's behaviour. I didn't check Firefox.

Comment: this will only initialize same values. may be I have to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for both questions is no. Looking at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax), there are two overloads for the `Array` function.

> A JavaScript array is initialized with the given elements, except in the case where a single argument is passed to the Array constructor and that argument is a number (see the arrayLength parameter below).
>
> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number.

Only these two possibilities exist, there is no overload for specifying both the size and the values of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and fill an array like so:

```js
let a = Array(100).fill(null)

console.log(a)
```

Or to increment your filled values:

```js
let i=0,a = Array(100).fill(0).flatMap(x=>[x+i++])

console.log(a)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: what if I want to add some specific string values ?

Comment: This is not clear. You want to assign specific string values, you need to define it in the first place! If it comes from a given algorithm, then you might see if an array generator function can suits! Otherwise a simple for loop should be enough! What's your goal? The less memory possible?

Comment: `flatMap` is still not supported by explorer and edge

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to create an array:

1) Literals

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a);
```

But you say you don't want to use it.

2) Array constructor:

```js
const a = new Array(10); //array of length 10
console.log(a); 

const b = new Array(1,2,3);
console.log(b); // array with elements 1,2,3
```

But you say that you don't want to go for it

3) Array.from

```js
const a = Array.from(new Array(10), (val, ind) => ind); // array of 10 values and map applied to these elements
console.log(a);
```

Over these 3 ways, you have the `Array.fill` method, which can be called with static values only:

```js
const a = new Array(10);
console.log(a.fill(5)); // array of 10 number elements with value of 5
```

Considering your case, maybe your solution could be to go with `Array.from`, using the map function you can provide as second parameter. 
You could think to create some function like the following:

```js
function createMyArray(length, start, end) {
  return Array.from(new Array(length), (val, ind) => ind >= start && ind <= end ? ind : undefined);
}

console.log(createMyArray(5, 2, 4));
console.log(createMyArray(5, 1, 3));
console.log(createMyArray(10, 2, 6));
```

The question you should ask to yourself is: Where and how is the data I want to use coming from? Otherwise this is really too much vague

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to initialize an array with array length and different values (not similar values) simultaneously using new Array() ?

No you cannot do that with the [Array constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-constructor) only.

An alternative way is to do it like this:

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
a.length = 10;
console.log(a);
```

> How to initialize a single integer value using new Array() ?

[You can't](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len). This is what happens when you try to do so according to the specification:

> `Array(len)`
>
> [...]
>
> - Let intLen be ToUint32(len).
> - If intLen ≠ len, throw a RangeError exception.
> - Let setStatus be Set(array, "length", intLen, true).
> - Assert: setStatus is not an abrupt completion.
>     Return array.

Use the other ways to create an array instead (e.g. `[1]` or [`Array.of(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different but related take on initializing an array without using an array literal.

```js
let arr = [...Array(10)].map((emptyItem, index) => index);
// [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I can't find documentation that matches how this expression is constructed, so I can't fully explain it. But it is using the spread syntax to spread 10 empty items into an array.